# Retrieve POST JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, grails

I'm writing my first Ajax request, on a Groovy/Grails platform.

```
    var newDataB = $.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    data: {source:"${source}"},
    success: function (response) { 
        jsonData = response;
        var res = JSON.parse(jsonData);
                alert(res);//
    }
});
```

Here is the response of my controller "url"

```
    def result = [ value: 'ok' ]
    render result as JSON
```

But it does not work and i get an error message in my browser

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data 
var res = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

I don't understand , the response seems to be a nice formatted JSON ?

EDIT i did a print as Paul suggests :

If i execute

```
    var newDataB = $.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {source:"${source}"},
    success: function (response) { 
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.value)
        jsonData = response;
    }
});
```

The first print is :

> Object { value="ok"}

The second print is

> ok

If i want to get the result, how is the proper way ?

Do i have to assign the value inside the statement "success: function (response) { "

doing something like

```
var result

var newDataB = $.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {source:"${source}"},
    success: function (response) { 
    result = response.value
    }
});

console.log("result : "+result);
```

This code works for me !!

Or perhaps there is a way to get the result, doing something like

```
var newDataB = $.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {source:"${source}"},
    success: function (response) { 

    }
});

var result = newDataB.response.somethingblablabla
```

or

```
var result = OneFunction(newDataB.response)
```

??????

Comment: are you sure you need to parse it? what if you `console.log(response)`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to parse it, if your server is providing json.

You can use dataType though to force jQuery to use a particular type:

```
var newDataB = $.ajax({
    method:'post',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {source:"${source}"},
    success: function (response) { 
        console.log(response);

    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry didn't remove your Parse. Try it like the above, response should just be a javascript object that you can work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can make object stringified before passing it to parse function by simply using  `JSON.stringify()`.

```
var newDataB = $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: "${createLink(controller: 'util',action: 'test')}",
        async: false,
        data: {source: "abc"},
        success: function (response) {
            jsonData = response;
            var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            console.log(res);//
        }
    });
```

Hopefully this may help.